# AppGyver Steroids tab Page Refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, steroids

I've got tabs setup for my app using the config file as so:

```
steroids.config.tabBar.tabs = [
   {
     title: "Index"
     icon: "icons/home.png"
     location: "http://localhost/index.html"
   },
   {
     title: "Top 10"
     icon: "icons/top10.png"
     location: "http://localhost/top10.html"
   },
   {
     title: "Buscar"
     icon: "icons/search.png"
     location: "http://localhost/search.html"
   },
   {
     title: "Favoritos"
     icon: "icons/favs.png"
     location: "http://localhost/favs.html"
   },
   {
     title: "Recomendado"
     icon: "icons/search.png"
     location: "http://localhost/search.html"
   },

 ]
```

This works fine. The problem is on the Favs page I am trying to get it to refresh at each time it's clicked. Right now I cannot find a way to do this. My current code is inside the `jQuery Document Ready` function so it works and refreshes the favs list when first entered. But in subsequent times to the page it doesn't refresh. How do I get this page to refresh my list each time it's entered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made this work using the `visibilitychange` event as described here:
http://docs.appgyver.com/en/edge/steroids_Steroids%20Native%20UI_events_events.visibilitychange.md.html

The final correct code to get this to work was:

```
document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", getFavs, false);
```

Placing this inside the JS file of the tab worked perfectly.